# IIS, магическая ошибка 404.13 - Not Found

Tags: python, windows, django, iis

Я использую IIS v10.0.14393.0 + Django,

При загрузки файла (размер 200 мб.) на сайт отдает ошибку 404.13 (ошибка IIS не Django) при этому если размер файла меньше чем некий лимит, то отдает 200.

В чем может быть проблема?

Если нужно, могу прикрепить `web.config`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поднимите лимиты размера запроса в конфиге:

Для модуля requestFiltering - скорее всего он у вас срабатывает:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <!-- This will handle requests up to 1024MB (1GB) -->
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

И для httpRuntime:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <!-- This will handle requests up to 1024MB (1GB) -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" timeout="3600" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Через UI, на server / site / app:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, спасибо, вариант с UI помог :)

Comment: Единственно все еще не понятно почему ошибка 404

Comment: @Denis потому что под 404 попадает случай "server ... is not
   willing to disclose that one exists" - т.е. сервер перестраховался, и не ответил клиенту ничего конкретного :)